# Rails Setting Devise Username as attribute of comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, devise

I'm new to rails and still figuring out which things belong in the model and which in the controller. I'm creating a simple comment model that belongs to articles. I have a attribute :commenter which is a string. I would like to get the username from the current_user (I'm using devise for my login feature) Would I do this in the create method of my controller?

Something like

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment.commenter = current_user.username
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Comment: It will be better if you add association between user and comment, like comment belongs to user and user has many comment. you can fetch the user of comment from user_id in comments table

Comment: @ezweizig are post and article same?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #should have user_id: integer in Comment
  belongs_to :post #should have post_id: integer in comment
  delegate :username, to: :user, allow_nil: true
end
```

In posts controller: -

```
    def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
      @comment.user = current_user
      if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Comment saved successfully!"
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
      else
        flash[:error] = @comment.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
      end
    end
```

After that you can get all user details of any comment:-

```
comment = Comment.find(#id_of_comment)
comment.username => #will return username because of delegation
```

[Reference for delegation](https://coderwall.com/p/wamyow/using-delegate-in-rails)